# Merged a Pull request merged multiple branches at once

Tags: git, github, merge, git-pull, pull-request

Yesterday I merged 1 pull request of a branch done by another developer that I am replacing while he is vacation into Master, the code changes in this branch was code reviewed and tested thoroughly.

All of the sudden he CI reported so many errors, totally unrelated to the changes done in that branch that merged in that pull request, so we assumed it was something else (lately we have been having issues with our CI, because is a plan to reorganize the CI).

This morning I got yelled by two different developers demanding an explanation on why I merged their branches when they are not done.

I have no idea how this is possible. In one Pull Request you merge different branches to the one that generated the Pull Request?

Can someone explain if this is possible, why and how.....

Comment: Without further information, my finger would be pointing at the members of your team who are complaining about your merging their branches when they are "not done."  In my opinion, if you open a pull request from a branch, it is open season for someone else to merge it.  If they opened those PRs in error, then it is _their_ problem, not yours.  But this assumes that there were really PRs open, and that you didn't someone merge by mistake without a PR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have experienced this where a developer has created `branch B` based on `branch A` which is yet to be merged in. Accepting the merge of `branch B` also accepts `branch A` up to the commit that `branch B` was created from.

The pull request will have included all the changes from `branch B` but not necessarily all of the changes from `branch A`. This can introduce broken/incomplete changes.

I hope the below helps to explain what I mean:

```
*
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
|    \
|     * commit to branch A
|     |
|     * commit to branch A
|    /|
|   / | 
|  *  | commit to branch B
|  |  |
|  |  * commit to branch A
|  |  
|  * commit to branch B
| /   
|/    
* merge branch B in to master (first two commits from branch A are included)
```

Comment: Yes it could be a possible reason on why this happen. Shouldn't Git avoid that to happen??

Comment: Git is doing the right thing here. The developer of `branch B` has created their branch from the wrong commit, or maybe they intended to as their changes were dependent on that commit in `branch A`?

Comment: We had to revert the PR. when the developer arrives from Vacation I will ask him what he did, and wh he didn't let me know. It has to be a reason for what he did.
Thank You @anierzad for your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately if his PR includes commits from someone else's branch, these may also be reverted (even after they merge their branch in). It might be worth looking through the commits on his branch and see what commit he used to create his branch. It should give you an idea of what's happened. No problem, anything to help.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent this from happening via a merge check in GitHub or Bitbucket?